# Framework for Delphi similar to Castor

Tags: xml, delphi, castor

Can anyone suggest: a framework for Delphi for work with XML / XSD like the one that makes [Castor for JAVA](http://www.castor.org/)?
Borland XML Data Binding does not offer - he is not flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any framework that will directly work like castor but I do know of this website http://robstechcorner.blogspot.com/2009/10/xml-serialization-control-via.html he wrote this strictly for serialization and deserialization. the only issue is that it will only work with D2010+.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally familear with Castor, but looking at it's website, the following links might be of interest to you:

[tiOPF](http://tiopf.sourceforge.net/Doc/Concepts/)

[InstantObjects](http://www.instantobjects.org/)

In addition, the [DeHL Framework](http://www.ohloh.net/p/DeHL) contains classes to enable XML serialization of objects.